# Trackpad Mimic Apple's Command Click

Tags: mouse, keyboard-layout, trackpad

I have a laptop that has a trackpad for the mouse. I'm not using all the multi-touch capabilities of the trackpad and am currently only able to get left click working. Is there any way to setup Win+Click as right click? This would be kind of like Command+Click on Apple machines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's do it!

1) Install [xdotool](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xdotool)

```
sudo aptitude install xdotool
```

2) Install [Compiz](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager)

```
sudo aptitude install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

3) Open Compiz

```
ccsm
```

4) Go to Commands then to "Commands" tab and add this to "Command line 0"
*sleep 0.1 && xdotool click --clearmodifiers 3*

[image]

5) Assign <kbd>Super</kbd> + Button1 at "Button Bindings" tab

[image]

And you're done.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for putting the time into this! :)

Comment: Glad to find stuff like this ;-)

Comment: @Glorfindel Thanks for updating the image links! However, you should include the working links to Wayback Machine instead of the dead originals IMHO.

Comment: You're welcome. To be honest, I don't think it really matters; it's rather easy to find the corresponding Wayback Machine link (or vice versa). And I have had some cases where the system rejected my edits because they changed too much, so from that point of view it's better to use the original URL.